# iphone dev changing tab bar item views programmatically

Tags: iphone

i have a tab bar application, now what i want to do is to change the views of a same tab bar item programmatically, means my requirement is that when application is running for the first time after installation (i will use NSUserDefaults for the "first time" thing) the first item of tab bar will contain the nib or view of Sign up class, that is at first run the sign up page or view will show on first item of tab bar, and then after that at every run the sign in screen will show at the same first item, now i am confused how to do it programmatically, coz i always set the nibs inside tab bar for each item using interface builder, now here it is different situation, plz. guide me in this how to go about that task, thanx and regards. Saad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITabBarController has  a method called `setViewControllers:animated:` that lets you provide an array of view controllers to be displayed.  If you detect it's not "first time" you can rearrange your list of controllers.

Comment: Thanx a lot Phillip Mills, but can u explain a little about this "If you detect it's not "first time" you can rearrange your list of controllers." Sorry i can't understand what u mean by that. Thanx again

Comment: also we will be providing views for all tab bar items in the array to that method?or can we provide it with only one or two views for any specific tab bar item?

Comment: Each tab on a bar represents a view controller.  When you call the method I mentioned, you pass it an array of view controllers in the order you want them to appear.  If you want to have an extra controller the first time or change their order, you can do it by changing what you put into the array.  (You seem to be saying that you already know how to use 'NSUserDefaults for the "first time" thing'.)

Comment: Thanx Phillip Mills it really explained a lot to me.